# Does media stream url require ATS? Though base url confirms to ATS?

Tags: ios, xcode, http, app-transport-security

I'm developing a app in which the base url has https and conforms to ATS as required by Apple, however the media streams url are still http, I mean when I call a a base URL

**For eg:** 
 https://test_app/api/v2/

The response will have list of video's available, these url's are http (http://test_app/videos/test.m3u8), is this allowed or every url should be ATS compliant? Does Apple reject this?

Comment: The people who closed this obviously do not understand ATS.  The question referenced as a duplicate was how to add exceptions.  While that may be a solution, this question specifically references media stream urls.  None of the answers in the referenced questions mention the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInMedia` exception, which is likely the right answer for this question.  As long as the app doesn't need to support iOS 9 devices, the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInMedia` exception should work for what you are asking.

Comment: Of the people who voted to close this as a duplicate, only one has significant iOS experience.  @msanford - consider removing your vote to close or voting to re-open based on the fact that this question deals with specifically media streams.  This is not a duplicate of the referenced question and it does not good to tag it as such.

Comment: Also @gobrewers14

Comment: And @Deep, please reconsider your duplicate vote.

Comment: I would ask this question again and we can hope it won't get falsely flagged as a duplicate again.  We can get an answer that might help you and others who are dealing with media streams in iOS9 +.